# Merge all arrays inside of an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

```
let fruit = {
    apple: [1, 2],
    orange: [3, 4],
    banana: [5, 6],
};

let allFruits = fruit.apple.concat(fruit.orange).concat(fruit.banana);
```

I can do something like this but what if I have like 20 fruit... Any other way maybe with lodash?

Comment: `Object.values(fruit).flat()`? What is the output you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here's how one can do it with lodash:

```
_.flatMap(fruit)
```

Yep, that simple. Two hidden tricks here:

- [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMap) (unlike [flatten](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatten)) works with Collections, and calls `Object.values()` for objects anyway
- it takes _.identity (x => x) as a mapper function by default

Answer (score 3):

No need to use lodash here. All you need to do is get a list of all the object values (with [Object.value()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)), then flatted it (with [yourArray.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat))

```js
let fruit = {
    apple: [1, 2],
    orange: [3, 4],
    banana: [5, 6],
};

console.log(Object.values(fruit).flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another vanilla JS solution using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```js
const fruit = {
  apple: [1, 2],
  orange: [3, 4],
  banana: [5, 6],
};

console.log(Object.values(fruit).reduce((t, c) => t.concat(...c), []));
```